# C# Abstract Class having Abstract Variables

Tags: c#, abstract-class

We have an abstract class called Game.

```
public abstract class Game
{
   protected Player player;

   public virtual void InitPlayer()
   {
      // steps
      player = new Player(xxxxxxx);
   }

   // Other methods manipulating data from player.
}
```

and there are two child classes of Game , let's say **GameA** and **GameB**.

```
public class GameA : Game
{     
    public override void InitPlayer()
    {
        base.InitPlayer();
    }
}
```

However, Player Variable in Game Class is also Abstract, having **PlayerGameA** and **PlayerGameB**.

```
public abstract class Player
{
}

public class PlayerGameA : Player
{
}
```

Note that Player and PlayerGameA Constructors have same arguments.

Now I have a problem about creating an instance of Abstract Class in InitPlayer Method. The result what I want is unifying result when creating an instance of GameA and calling gameA.InitPlayer() will create **playerGameA** ,and still other methods from GameClass needs to be able to manipulate data from that **player** variable.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a number of approaches. A straightforward one is to make your concrete sublclass of `Game` responsible for providing a concrete implementation of `Player`, e.g.:

```
public abstract class Game
{
    protected Player player;

    protected void InitPlayer(Player concretePlayer)
    {
        // steps
        player = concretePlayer;
    }
}

public class GameA : Game
{
    public void InitPlayer()
    {
        base.InitPlayer(new PlayerGameA());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A better approach is to make `Game` accept a generic parameter `TPlayer`.

But you should place any non-generic functionality in a `GameBase` non-generic class

```cs
public abstract class GameBase
{
    // non generic functionality here
}

public abstract class Game<TPlayer> : GameBase where TPlayer : Player
{
    protected TPlayer player;

    protected void InitPlayer(TPlayer concretePlayer)
    {
        // steps
        player = concretePlayer;
    }
}

public class GameA : Game<PlayerGameA>
{
    public void InitPlayer()
    {
        base.InitPlayer(new PlayerGameA());
    }
}
```